# Unable to Repo.Insert a value into a belongs_to field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I currently have a table that has a field with a belongs_to relationship with another table. When I try and use Repo.insert to add a value to this field I receive an 'is_invalid' error. The error is generated by both seed file and manual command line.

The struct to insert is:

```
Repo.insert! %Customer_list{
    age: 24,
    first_name: "Tony",
    last_name: "Stark",
    customer_id: "D00001",
    list_date: ~D[2018-09-13],
    consultant_id: 8
  }
```

The model:

```
defmodule InformAPI.CTL.Customer_list do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset


  schema "customer_lists" do
    field :age, :integer
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :customer_id, :string
    field :list_date, :date
    belongs_to :consultant_id, InformAPI.CTL.Customer_list_consultants

    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(customer_list, attrs) do
    Customer_list
    |> cast(attrs, [:customer_id, :first_name, :age, :last_name,  :list_date, :consultant_id])
    |> validate_required([:customer_id, :first_name, :age, :last_name,  :consultant_id, ])
  end
end
```

All fields except 'consultant_id' can be entered correctly. The 'consultant_id' is a bigint type field in the Postgres DB. The Customer_lists db has the following keys:

```
customer_lists_consultant_id_fkey
customer_lists_pkey
customer_lists_consultant_id_index
```

And the customer_lists_consultants table has:

```
customer_list_consultants_pkey
```

I'm not sure what is invalid. The consultant_id field won't accept any type of value (String, int etc).

Comment: Try changing `belongs_to :consultant_id` to `belongs_to :consultant` (remove `_id`).

Comment: That absolutely worked! Would you mind putting it into answer so I can accept it and explain a little bit about the why it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ecto, by default, assumes that the actual database column of a `belongs_to` relationship is the name of the declaration plus `"_id"`. In your case, Ecto assumed that the column's name was `consultant_id_id` and so the value of `consultant_id` was being ignored by `cast`.

The fix is to change the name of the relationship to just `consultant`.

```
belongs_to :consultant, InformAPI.CTL.Customer_list_consultants
```